# How to understand $2^{e^{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

$2^{e^{x}}$ is an exponent over a exponent. It is confusing.
How to understand it? 
Can I simplify it?

Comment: It increases very rapidly - WAY faster than the gamma function. No, you can't "simplify" it, whatever that means, though you can rewrite it as $e^{log(2) e^x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't simplify it.  It increases *very* [rapidl](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%28e%5Ex%29)y with $x$.  We read it as $2^{(e^x)}$ because $(2^e)^x=2^{ex}$

Comment: How to understand it? Because I need to apply an integration on it.

Comment: If you're not sure how to integrate it, then I'd suggest you ask that as a question directly. @Fan

Comment: If you need to integrate a function, please ask the question you have.  It may be hard, but there may be a useful estimate.

Comment: $2^{e^{x}}$ is equal to $2^{ex}$?

Comment: @Fan no that is not same

Comment: How to understand it then?

Comment: Try some values. For x = 1, $2^{e^x} = 2^e$ which is between $4 = 2^2$ and $8 = 2^3$. For x = 2 it's $2^{e^2}$ which is between $2^4$ and $2^9$. You can see that it grow very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The way exponent towers work is you go from the top down. So:
$$4^{3^2}=4^9=262,\!144$$
$$2^{e^4}\approx2^{54.59815}\approx27,\!269,\!731,\!868,\!896,\!801.97168$$
$$2^{3^4}=2^{81}=2,\!417,\!851,\!639,\!229,\!258,\!349,\!412,\!352$$
$$10^{10^2}=10^{100}=10,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!\\
000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!\\
000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!\\
000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000$$

It's interesting how $2^{e^4}$ is around 30 million billion, but $2^{3^4}$ is around 2 million billion billion (that is, around 70 million times larger).